# W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release:

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY” without terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal)

After i run sudo aptitude update i get the below error:

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4784331D8BAF9A6F